# ssh_exchange_identification Can't Access to SSH Amazon EC2 (Lock Out)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, port, connection

I get an error in terminal when I'm trying to access my instance in Amazon EC2. I use Centos 6.x server WHM/cPanel, i have access to WHM, but i **DON'T** have a complete access to FTP or SSH.

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 2020: Connection refused
```

**Procedures i have taken to fix the issue.**

1. Reboot Instance
2. Detach and attach the volume to another instance
3. Use other SSH softwares
4. Security Group Check in Amazon (Port 2020 is allowed & All Traffic
   is Allowed in Inbound)
5. I added Custom TCP/SSH 2020 specially to my IP in Security Group as-well
6. clear entire Mac Cache

**Telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 2020** 
 
**Respond**

```
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xx.xx.xx.xx: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use port 2020? The default ssh port is 22.

Comment: Cause i change the port to 2020 before i lock out, i did it for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means that there's nothing listening on host xx.xx.xx.xx port 2020 for incoming connection attempts. In other words, `sshd` isn't running in your EC2 instance, or if it is running, it's not listening on that particular IP address and port.

You will need to get into the EC2 instance to check and correct the SSH server configuration. You say you had just reconfigured the ssh server to listen on port 2020 instead of 22; maybe that change didn't "take" and it's still listening on port 22.

Comment: I did try 22 and 2020 both refuse. but i do agree with you on Port is not listening. i just don't know how to SSH in different way so i can change it. i do have access to WHM is the a way to change the configuration file from there?

Comment: if the port is not 2020 then why in cPanel is saying SFTP 2020, here is an screenshot of the SFTP http://i.stack.imgur.com/1atQD.png